# Get image from local path in php

Tags: php, excel, image, cakephp

I am working on a bulk upload project using excel sheet and using CakePHP 3.2 for writing application.

I have an excel sheet with a column to give image to be uploaded.

User have 3 choices to go with either

> 1. Upload images to a pre defined directory before bulk upload and give the name of the image in the cell and image will be automatically
>      selected from path.
> 2. Give the url of the image (*http://website/path/image.jpg*)
> 3. Give the path of the image if it is on local machine. *Ex.,* **C:\user\pictures\image.jpg** *if windows*, and
>      **/home/user/picture/image.jpg** if *linux*

This is what I'm doing to save images

```
$p_image = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(30, $row)->getValue();
if (filter_var($p_image, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
   // get image from url
   $full_image_path = $p_image;
} else {

    // get image from folder
    $path = Configure::read('media.bulkUpload.pre.product');

    // full path of the image from root directory
    $full_image_path = $path . DS . $p_image;
}
$upload_path = Configure::read('media.upload') . DS . 'files' . DS;

// new name of image
$img_new_name = uniqid('img_').round(microtime(true) * 1000).rand(1,100000);

if ($full_image_path) {

   // generate uuid directory name
   $dir = Text::uuid();
   // create new directory
   mkdir($upload_path.$dir, 0777, true);

   // save file
   try {
     $img = new \abeautifulsite\SimpleImage($full_image_path);

     // save image of original size   
     $img->best_fit(850,1036)->save($upload_path.$dir.'/'.$img_new_name.'.jpg');

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
     }
}
```

Image upload using url and pre ftp upload is working fine. But, how could I get image from the path of local system and then save them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this without the users uploading the image themselves. You cannot retrieve a file from the client's filesystem from an external server where you run your php.